# Transform UIViewController with UITableView into UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

In Storyboard I created UIViewController with UITableView as root view's subview. UITableView has Static Cells content. Unfortunately I had "Error:Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances" while compilation.

My Question is: Could I transform UIViewController with UITableView into UITableViewController, because it will be very hard to recreate my UITableView in new UITableViewController from scratch.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't.  When you select a UIViewController or a UITableViewController from the object list on the right in the storyboard editor, it initializes that scene with specific properties for that intended class.  The best you can do is drag in a new UITableViewController and manually copy over your cells

Comment: Thank for idea, i just drag sections to new uitableviewcontroller